# How to assign a shortcut Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, customization, system-settings

Every time I try to assign a shortcut to switch the language by using (Shift+Alt) the system does not accept it. However it accepts other shortcut
buttons.